# Which NoSql databases can scale to handle over 2 billion rows?

Tags: .net, nosql, scalability

Which NoSql databases can scale to handle over 2 billion rows without significant performance problems ?

Idealy it would work well with .net as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB , also  it's officially supported C# / .NET driver for MongoDB

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

MongoDB tested with following IDE versions:

Visual Studio 2010
Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data your rows contains. Are they numerical data or large documents? Do you refer to the reading or the writing performance? Does the database need to handle true ACID transactions or do you plan to add the data in a batch and then do analytical queries?

Starcounter is an In-Memory, true ACID transactional database that is object oriented and uses a native .NET api. (You just program your regular classes and use an attribute to indicate what classes to be persistent)

As said. To guide you it would be helpful to know if you need a OLTP or OLAP kind of database.